# What's the simplest way to assign unique sliders to each clicked element in this case?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a table with a javascript function where when a table cell is clicked, the entire row will be removed and the clicked cell will be copied to the leftmost position with a slider opening up on the right. However, I only have a universal slider for all clicked elements but I want to make each table cell's slider unique. What's the best approach for that in this case?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var table = document.getElementById("TrendGames");
  table.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var clickedCell = event.target.closest("td");
    if (clickedCell) {
      handleCellClick(clickedCell);
    }
  });
});

function handleCellClick(clickedCell) {
  const row = clickedCell.parentElement;
  const cells = row.children;
  const display = cells[cells.length - 1].style.display ? "" : "none";

  // Hide/Show all cells
  for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
    cells[i].style.display = display;
  }
  if (display) {
    // First click (third, fifth, ...)
    // Copy(!) the clicked cell in the leftmost position
    const newCell = clickedCell.cloneNode(true);
    newCell.style.display = "";
    newCell.colSpan = cells.length;
    row.insertBefore(newCell, row.firstChild);
    // Open the slider and display information
    openSlider(newCell);
  } else {
    // Remove the cell that was inserted on previous click
    clickedCell.remove();
    closeSlider(clickedCell);
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="TrendGames">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="cell1">
        Cell 1
        <img class="GameCover" src=".png" alt="cell1" />
      </td>
      <td id="cell2">
        Cell 2
        <img class="GameCover" src=".png" alt="cell2" />
      </td>
      <td id="cell31">
        Cell 3
        <img class="GameCover" src=".png" alt="cell3" />
      </td>
      <td id="cell4">
        Cell 4
        <img class="GameCover" src=".png" alt="cell4" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: If you're already using `const`, don't use `var`. Use `let`, because `var` scopes things to the function and all `var` declarations get hoisted (i.e. it doesn't matter where _you_ declare it, _JS_ will move it to the start of the function. Declared it in a `for(var i...`? Too bad, you actually told JS to declare `i` at the top of your function, outside your for loop). Use `let` and `const` for new code.

Comment: How am I supposed to understand that each table cell's slider unique?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out, if I should add an id to every table cell and go on from there.